# Unfamiliar with notation : $S \subseteq [d]$ where {$d, w_{1},w_{2}, ..., w_{d}$}

Tags: notation

What does $S \subseteq [d]$ mean in the context of {$d, w_{1},w_{2}, ..., w_{d}$}? I don't get what [d] stands for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly $[d]=\{1,2,\ldots,d\}$; this is a fairly standard notation. Check to see whether the context shows that $S$ is being used as a set of subscripts on the $w$’s.